# DynamoDB ConditionExpression without using ExpressionAttributeValues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I need to make a comparison in a ConditionExpression of the form '(#i.body_uncommon = 1)' without using ExpressionAttributeValues, what should the syntax be? I looked at all the documentation and did not find an example

For example so:

```
 response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'ID': "jr_test"
    }
    , ConditionExpression='(#i.body_uncommon = 1)'
    , UpdateExpression=final_str

    , ExpressionAttributeNames={
        "#i": "items"
    }
)
```

But this code throws a syntax error in the place: token: "1", near: "= 1)"

Comment: according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeValues.html), "If you need to compare an attribute with a value, define an expression attribute value as a placeholder". In multiple places in the DDB documentation, there are notes saying "an expression attribute value must be defined for ___" such as the `attribute_type` function in [ConditionExpression Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions).

Comment: Why do you think you *need* to do this without using ExpressionAttributeValues?

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB does not accept literal values within expressions. Expressions must use placeholders in conjunction with the `ExpressionAttributeValues` parameter to specify literal values.

This API essentially enforces best practices to prevent injection attacks.

From [Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeValues.html):

> If you need to compare an attribute with a value, define an expression attribute value as a placeholder.

Even functions that accept specific values as arguments, such as the [`attribute_type` function for a ConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions), specify that the values must be defined using expression attribute values.

> You must use an expression attribute value for the `type` parameter.